# vgg16 model with CONVLSTM2D

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am using the following code to classify videos using LSTM. Features from each frame are extracted using VGG16 model. I am also interested to extract features in spatial domain. I understand from keras documentation that CONVLSTM2D does this. But I am not sure how to use features from vgg16 when using CONVLSTM2D.

```
frames=19
channels=3
rows=224
columns=224
classes=2


video = Input(shape=(frames,
                     rows,
                     columns, channels))
cnn_base = VGG16(input_shape=(rows,columns,channels),weights="imagenet",include_top=False, pooling = 'avg' )





encoded_frames = TimeDistributed(cnn_base)(video)
encoded_sequence = LSTM(256)(encoded_frames)
hidden_layer = Dense(output_dim=1024, activation="relu")(encoded_sequence)
outputs = Dense(output_dim=classes, activation="softmax")(hidden_layer)
model = Model([video], outputs)
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: What is it that you don't understand or you are not sure about? Your model seems fine. Have you trained it and gotten low accuracy?

Comment: Well... just use ConvLSTM2D instead of LSTM... everything seems fine indeed.

Answer (score 0):

ConvLSTM2D requires image like inputs (height, width, channels). So you can use the output of layers in VGG before later Flatten and the Dense layers where the output is still of shape (height, width, channels) and feed that into ConvLSTM2D.